# Sanitizing response JSON from Spring MVC Controller using JSON Sanitizer?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, owasp

I want to intercept the JSON sent back from a Spring MVC Rest Controller and run it through a sanitizer that ensures it's valid and HTML escapes any dodgy characters. (Possibly the [OWASP JSON Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_JSON_Sanitizer))

We use the Jackson HTTP Message converter to convert the @ResponseBody to JSON, as far as I can see once I return the object as a @ResponseBody I lose control of it.

Is there a sensible way to intercept the JSON as a String to run sanitization code on it?

I'm currently investigating three avenues:

1. Writing a Filter and ResponseWrapper which sanitizes the JSON before it's sent back to the client.
2. Extending the JSON Mapper somehow to provide sanitized JSON.
3. Writing a Handler Interceptor and using it to modify the response.

I'm not sure if either of these will work or if there is a more sensible third option.

Comment: Why would you HTML-escape JSON? JSON is supposed to contain unformatted data, so that any kind of client can use it to display it however it wants. And if a client chooses to insert this data in HTML, then it's the client's responsibility to do it properly. Not the server.

Comment: My understanding of the problem is that we want to ensure that any maliciously inserted data can't do anything naughty if it's requested from the backend.

I've been called in at the 11th hour and told to ensure that following characters from are escaped in the output of and JSON messages:

 %, &, *, $, #, @, !, \, /, :, *, ?, ", <, >, |, ;, '

Answer (score 11):

I know this answer may be too late, but I needed to do the same thing, so I added a serializer to the JSON mapper.

The web configuration:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        // the list is empty, so we just add our converter
        converters.add(jsonConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter<Object> jsonConverter() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
                .json()
                .serializerByType(String.class, new SanitizedStringSerializer())
                .build();
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }
}
```

And the string serializer:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NonTypedScalarSerializerBase;

public class SanitizedStringSerializer extends NonTypedScalarSerializerBase<String> {

    public SanitizedStringSerializer() { 
        super(String.class); 
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        jgen.writeRawValue("\"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(value) + "\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated! 
You can find more information here:

https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-webmvcconfigureradapter-is-deprecated/