# SpringBoot using JSON Sanitizer?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have set of rest apis written using springboot restcontroller. Each api returns different object types that gets converted to json using jackson lib. Is there a way to encode/sanitize the json just before they are returned to the client ? Do not want to replicate the code for each api.

Comment: i think, you are looking for solution mentioned in this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137544/sanitizing-response-json-from-spring-mvc-controller-using-json-sanitizer

Comment: @Yogi , Tommy  Thank you. I have looked into both of them. Both of them tells how to work with String data types. In my case each API returns different objects. I want to do sanitization just after json string gets created from the objects or probably pass a flag to jackson if exists for escaping chars. This way i do not need to handle for individual object types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `@ControllerAdvice` class that implements `ResponseBodyAdvice` and will be executed after the action of the controller and before the response is written to the caller. For the method `beforeBodyWrite` you get the current body response as input and can return the modified body as response.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class HeaderModifierAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        return "new rewritten response";
    }
}
```

helpful blog article: https://mtyurt.net/post/spring-modify-response-headers-after-processing.html