# Spring boot Sanitizing json with @RequestBody

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot 2.0.2.

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/process", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response<String> abcd(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {
        System.out.println(payload);
        Response<String> s = new Response<>();
        s.setData("aaaa");
        return s;
    }
```

So basically input is json. Now I want to sanitize my json via some library(not part of question).

My question is how can I do this? I mean where should I write this code?
I want a centralized solution like using AOP (aspect-oriented programming)?

How do i write my AOP?
What i just want is that I should get input as json, and return sanitized json and request body works as it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sanitizing response JSON from Spring MVC Controller using JSON Sanitizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137544/sanitizing-response-json-from-spring-mvc-controller-using-json-sanitizer)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I need a solution from AOP

Comment: "centralized solution" for "sanitizing" request-body would suggest an request-interceptor or filter. The converter-component used by Spring for deserializing JSON is usually Jackson's `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` - there would also be a good place for a "centralized" sanitation filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with AOP you could write an after advice for the code doing the json serialization and do the sanitize you want there. I think Spring boot use `ObjectMapper` to do the serialization. You can try to add your advice to the method `writeValueAsString` in the ObjectMapper class.

You can find a short intro on how to use AOP with Spring boot on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop.